# Implementing Backspace and Enter Keys on a Qt Virtual Keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard

I'm implementing a virtual keyboard as in input panel widget based on the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-inputpanel.html). I've able to have characters appear in a text widget by emitting a signal like so `emit characterGenerated( char )` -- please refer to `buttonClicked(QWidget *w)` method in the [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-inputpanel.html). Unfortunately this approach does not work for the enter and backspace keys. I'd appreciate advise on possible workarounds.

If it matters, I'm developing in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `MyInputPanelContext::sendCharacter` function in the linked example. When `QKeyEvent keyPress` object is constructed, `character.unicode()` is used as the second argument. However, you can also use `Qt::Key` values as the second argument. For example:

```
QKeyEvent keyPress(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Backspace, Qt::NoModifier);
```

You should rewrite this method to accept `int` argument that will be passed to `QKeyEvent` constructor and change `characterGenerated(QChar)` signal to `keyGenerated(int)` so you can send a special key (`Qt::Key_Backspace`) or a character key (`character.unicode()`) using the same signal and slot.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm not quite sure how to make this technique work for characters such as the Euro symbol for which there is no Qt Key.

Comment: My workaround is basically to test for the character and raise an event with `Qt::Key_Enter` or `Qt::Key_Backspace` if the enter or backspace key is pressed. Else raise an event with the character unicode information.

Answer (score 0):

This one is specific to that example. I turned '*' button to backspace by modifying sendcharacter code (in myinputpanelcontext.cpp) to this. Please have a look. Hope it helps.

```cpp
void MyInputPanelContext::sendCharacter(QChar character)
{
     QPointer<QWidget> w = focusWidget();

     if (!w)
         return;

     QKeyEvent keyPress(QEvent::KeyPress, character.unicode(), Qt::NoModifier, QString(character));
     QKeyEvent keybkspc(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Backspace, Qt::NoModifier);

     if(character != '*')
     {
        QApplication::sendEvent(w, &keyPress);
     }
     else
     {
         QApplication::sendEvent(w, &keybkspc);
     }
     if (!w)
         return;

     QKeyEvent keyRelease(QEvent::KeyPress, character.unicode(), Qt::NoModifier, QString());
     QApplication::sendEvent(w, &keyRelease);
}
```